# Scala duck typing pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

I have a case class like the following:

```
// parent class
sealed abstract class Exp()

// the case classes I want to match have compatible constructors
case class A (a : Exp, b : Exp) extends Exp
case class B (a : Exp, b : Exp) extends Exp
case class C (a : Exp, b : Exp) extends Exp

// there are other case classes extending Exp that have incompatible constructor, e.g.
//     case class D (a : Exp) extends Exp
//     case class E () extends Exp
// I don't want to match them
```

I want to match:

```
var n : Exp = ...
n match {
    ...
    case e @ A (a, b) => 
        foo(e, a)
        foo(e, b)
    case e @ B (a, b) => 
        foo(e, a)
        foo(e, b)
    case e @ C (a, b) => 
        foo(e, a)
        foo(e, b)
    ...
}

def foo(e : Exp, abc : Exp) { ... }
```

is there a way to merge that three cases into a single case (without adding an intermediate parent class to A,B,C)? I can't change the definition of A, B, C, or Exp. Some sort of:

```
var n : Exp = ...
n match {
    ...
    case e @ (A | B | C) (a, b) => // invalid syntax
        foo(e, a)
        foo(e, b)
    ...
}
```

which obviously does not work, and neither do:

```
var n : Exp = ...
n match {
    ...
    case e @ (A (a, b) | B (a, b) | C (a, b)) => // type error
        foo(e, a)
        foo(e, b)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While the following "solution" is really just a different way of writing what you already have, it might help if you need to use the same `match` in more than one place and want to avoid code duplication.

The following custom unapply:

```
object ExpABC {
    def unapply(e:Exp):Option[(Int, Int)] = e match {
        case A(a, b) => Some(a, b)
        case B(a, b) => Some(a, b)
        case C(a, b) => Some(a, b)
        case _ => None
    }
}
```

allows you to write

```
n match {
    case e @ ExpABC(a, b) =>
        println(e)
        println(a)
        println(b)
}
```

This way you don't need to modify the original classes at all. I'm not aware of a better way to do this that doesn't involve modifying the A/B/C classes, but I'm eager to learn @ Stackoverflow ;)